# RDP stops working, until user opens configuration and clicks into the computer field

Tags: windows, rdp, microsoft

We have VPN tunnel configured between office 1 and main office. From office 1 (Windows 10) we are connecting via RDP to the server (MS server) using internal VPN IP.

From time to time, it happens that RDP connection does not work anymore. Everything else works, internet, pinging the internal address of the server, all of it. Except RDP, it just won't connect. Even reboot of the clients machine does not help.

Fun fact is that to fix this, user can open RDP configuration and only click in the "computer" field. Without any changes, if user now clicks to connect, suddenly the RDP works again. From this procedure on, it works as usually.

What can be the culprit? Some weird cache? How could we solve the issue, so that user doesn't have to open the settings?

Answer (score 0):

Can you brief the connectivity to the RDP device.

Check possibility of IPS devices in between the connection(check the connection status).Or else check the packet capture and whichg state the conection is terminated from the destination device.

Regards,
Kannan K R

Comment: There are 8 more clients, that are connecting to that server and they don't have the problem at the same time. They all get it occasionally, but not together. So we can say that RDP works normally on the server side.

I will try to diagnose further, but it is in production so as usually nobody has time for that...